# MvvmCross iOS: how to dismiss a view controller when use IMvxModelTouchView

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have used IMvXModelTouchView for a custom popup screen animation. And, I have a close button on this popup view. What is the proper way to switch back to a previous view?

Here is my code look like:

```
public class PopupView 
     : MvxViewController, IMvxModalTouchView
{
    public PopupView()
    {
        ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.PageSheet;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        Title = "Map";
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var closeButton = new UIButton(new RectangleF(0, 0, 50, 30));
        closeButton.TouchUpInside += CloseButtonClicked();
        Add(closeButton);
    }

    private EventHandler CloseButtonClicked()
    {
        return (sender, args) => NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }
}
```

It worked, the first time when I click this close button, but it crash when I tried to pop up this view again.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are probably using the standard `MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter` which only expects one modal view/viewModel to be displayed at a time, and which expects that view/viewModel to be cleared using `Close(this)` from the ViewModel.

See: [MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs#L29](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs#L29)

If you have strong ideas about your UI, then (in my opinion) your best bet is to write your own custom presenter - then you can open/close/hide/show whatever you want. For more on writing custom presenters, see some of the links and videos from: http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html